# ngAfterViewChecked is keep calling in a loop

Tags: angular

I am using ngAfterViewChecked  to call a function that initialize some css role using jquery

my code is like this

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){
   console.log("ngAfterViewChecked");
   this.callJqueryMethod();

   } 


 callJqueryMethod(){
    jQuery(".leftText").each(function () {
        var $this = jQuery(this);

        $this.height($this.parent("div").find(".boxWarp").height()+42);
    });

    jQuery(window).resize(function () {



        jQuery(".leftText ").each(function () {
            var $this = jQuery(this);
            $this.height($this.parent("div").find(".boxWarp").height() + 42);
        });
    });


 }
```

for some reason ngAfterViewChecked keep calling over and over in a loop.

I must use this lifecycle hook, in other lifecycle the doom isn't ready.

does anyone encountered that kind of problem?I can't see a errors in the console

Answer (score 2):

Looks like jquery is triggering the update of your DOM which in fact calls ngAfterViewChecked() and this one calls jquery again, so you have a loop between jquery and  ngAfterViewChecked().

Try to avoid jquery with this hook.